# "enhance" object to inherited class javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two classes defined, say Animal and Rabbit. Rabbit extends Animal and has some additional methods apart from those defined in Animal.

When the user runs my app, an instance of Animal is created (say myAnimal). Then depending on something that the user does, I may need to "enhance"/cast myAnimal into the inherited class Rabbit. Is this possible in Modern JavaScript so the additional methods defined in Rabbit may now be available to myAnimal?

Comment: Sure. Why not. Buts its not clear what exactly you want to do. Define "what the user does". A gues into the wild `Object.setPrototypeOf()` perhaps?

Comment: @Marc Simply overwriting the prototype is not sufficient, the subclass may have setup in the constructor etc. A better approach would be to make the subclass constructable from the parent, so e.g. make `new Rabbit(new Animal())` or `Rabbit.fromAnimal(new Animal())` valid etc.

Comment: Since JS uses prototypical inheritance, if you make changes to the Animal object, it will be reflected in objects which have it as their prototype.

Comment: @Marc : User selects additional analysis options by checking a checkbox. Those additional analysis methods are available in Rabbit.

Comment: @Etheryte that sounds interesting because I do need all the data and methods that are already present in myAnimal. Can you give a tiny bit of code example please where some arrays created in myAnimal remain available when Rabbit is created from Animal? Thx.

Comment: Read just now that setPrototypeOf can be performance intensive

Answer (score 1):

@Etheryte 's suggestion worked. I defined a static method fromAnimal in Rabbit which creates a new Rabbit, sets properties of given Animal (myAnimal) and returns that instance. It includes all processing that myAnimal has undergone so far.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

no you can not. 
other way, you can create an instance of `Rabbit` - `myRabbit` with properties of `myAnimal`. (comment of @Etheryte above)

 or use `decorator` of Typescript

Comment: Would this mean writing code to copy all properties of myAnimal to Rabbit? That would be too cumbersome and seems to defeat the purpose of defining an inherited class. Can you share a bit of code sample please?

Will read what decorator does.